# Python - Read and plot data from a .csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, graphing

I have a .csv full of GDP data by year for different countries.  I want read the file and plot the data of only a select few of the countries in the .csv file.  So far I have:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('The_data.csv', dtype=str, delimiter=',', names=None, usecols=np.arange(0,17))
```

which I think lets me read the data.  How do I use matplotlib to generate a graph of GDP change over the years, but only of certain countries?

Comment: You *think* it is letting you read the data? Have you tried it? In that case, what does `data` look like?

Answer (score -1):

```
with open(The_data.csv) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    My_list=[]
    for line in content:         
        My_list.add(line.split(';') )
```

or use CSV module https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html